# Does bash operator =~ respect locale?

Tags: regex, bash, locale, posix-ere

Does bash operator `=~` as described in the [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) section of the bash manual respect locale?

The documentation alludes to it using POSIX extended regular expressions:

> the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex3)

The POSIX extended regular expression manpage `man 7 regex` describes that they are locale dependent. Specifically concerning bracket expressions it says:

> If two characters in the list are separated by '-', this is shorthand for the full range of characters between those two (inclusive) in the collating sequence, for example, "[0-9]" in ASCII matches any decimal digit. ... Ranges are very collating-sequence-dependent, and portable programs should avoid relying on them.

All of this suggests to me that the regular expressions used with the bash `=~` operator should respect locale; however my testing does not seem to bear this out:

```
$ export LANG=en_US
$ export LC_COLLATE=en_US
$ [[ B =~ [A-M] ]] && echo matched || echo unmatched
matched
$ [[ b =~ [A-M] ]] && echo matched || echo unmatched
unmatched
```

I would expect the last command to also echo `matched` as the collating sequence for `en_US` is `aAbBcCdD...` as opposed to the `ABCD...abcd...` sequence in the `C` (ASCII) locale.

Do I set my locale incorrectly? Is bash not setting up the locale correctly for POSIX extended regular expressions to use the locale?

---

Some more experimentation based on Marcos's answer:

When in `en_US` locale, `[a-M]` apparently matches any lower case character `a` through `z` and any uppercase character `A` through `M`. That would suggest a collating order of `abcd...ABCD...` instead of `aAbBcCdD...`. Switching to the `C` locale using `[a-M]` will result in an exit code of `2` from the Conditional Construct instead of `0` or `1`. This indicates an invalid regular expression, which makes sense as in the `C` locale `a` comes after `M` in the collating order.

So, locale is definitely being used in the POSIX extended regular expressions. However the bracket expression does not follow the collating order I would expect. Do bracket expressions perhaps use something other than the collating order?

---

**edit1:** updated to use the actual correct `en_US` collating sequence.
**edit2:** added further findings.

Comment: Not the resolution of your problem, but `echo $'a\nb\nc\nA\nB\nC' | sort` suggests that `a` sorts *before* `A` in a US locale.  A better example would be `g` (or anything in `b..l`).

Comment: Works here with cygwin as expected: `export LC_COLLATE=en_US && [[ b =~ [A-M] ]] && echo match` yields match.

Comment: @yacc, hmmn, interesting. I'm simply using the locales provided by glibc. And looking at the output from something like `ls` seems to indicate that the collating order is correct, so why is bash behaving so strangely...

Comment: And when I put `export LC_COLLATE=C` the regex won't match. Regardless of `set -o posix` or not. Maybe it's an issue of the build version. Or some tty mumbo jumbo.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually aAbB... and not AaBb.
Try this: `touch {a..z}; touch {A..Z}; ls -1 | sort`.
See?

So

```
$ [[ a =~ [a-M] ]] && echo matched || echo unmatched
matched
$ [[ A =~ [a-M] ]] && echo matched || echo unmatched
matched
```

Comment: This does not answer the main OP question. Even if the correct order is  `aAbB...` and not `AaBb...`as OP wrote, we would expect a "match" in this test : `[[ b =~ [A-M] ]] && echo matched || echo unmatched` . But we still get "unmatched" result. Your solution using `[a-M]` will only work because this actually includes `a to z` and then `A to M` , as would appear in a C locale situation.

Comment: Heh, indeed, it's `aAbBcC...` never knew that. I'll update the question for correctness. But indeed, as George mentions, even when using `b` instead of `a` in the test, the test still fails.

Comment: But the answer works here for me, GNU bash, version 4.3.46(7)-release (i686-pc-cygwin). `export LC_COLLATE=en_US && [[ b =~ [A-M] ]] && echo match` : match.